# Adjusting fixed menu and the content of a page with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a menu bar which is fixed so as the user scrolls it remains at the top of the page.

However, I want a gap between the menu and the page (called it pageTest below).

I tried changing the margin in the .menu to

> margin: 0 0 50px; 0;

However nothing happens? My [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waLpk14a/200/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="menu">

</div>

<div class="content">

</div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.menu {  
  background-color: #9FACEC;    /* Medium blue */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

.content {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 800px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: fixed` removes an element from the normal document flow. Setting a margin on this element will have no effect on the surrounding elements.

Your margin should be added to `.content` rather than `.menu`.

`.menu` would also need `top: 0` to prevent the margin from pushing it down the page.

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #9FACEC;
  /* Medium blue */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0; /* Added */
}

.content {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: 125px; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">

</div>

<div class="content">


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use top:0 in Menu div 
and give the same margin as height of Nav in you case is 100px 
working code is here

```
<body>


<div class="menu">

</div>

<div class="pageTest">


</div>

</body>
```

css edited

```
    body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.menu {  
  background-color: #9FACEC;    /* Medium blue */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  top:0;
}


.pageTest {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top:150px
}
```

I hope i answered your question

Answer (score 1):

**See :** [Case where .pageTest is above .menu](https://jsfiddle.net/0fx2wepz/) 
As `position:fixed` on `.menu` div removes the element from the flow, and the `.pageTest` div is then adjusted accordingly which make it to start from the top position of document in this case.

So, we can just give **`position:relative`** to `.pageTest` div to manipulate the **`top property`**.

**`.pageTest {
  //other css properties..
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
}`**

Providing **`top:100px`** will start the `.pageTest` div just after the `.menu` div. 
So added **`50px`** to have a gap between the two divs.

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.menu {  
  background-color: #9FACEC;    /* Medium blue */
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}


.pageTest {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px; // can be adjusted accordingly
}
```

```html
<body>


<div class="menu">

</div>

<div class="pageTest">


</div>

</body>
```